# MuJoCo via mujoco-py interface FetchReach-v1 scenario robotic action delay

Tags: openai-gym, mujoco

Dear MuJoCo community,

in last few days I was working with a simple **FetchReach-v1** scenario in **open-ai gym MuJoCo environment**. I was trying to apply the MPC (Model Predictive Control) to this scenario which basically generates new trajectory points for the robotic arm. The MPC is configured so to provide feasible velocities and accelerations to the robot, so that it will achieve the next point within the timestep, which is equals to: `dt = sim.nsubsteps * sim.model.opt.timestep`.

**The problem:** After applying the action to the environment I figured out that the next position of the grip is not equal to the position I expected. First I start thinking that the acceleration and/or the velocities of my MPC algorithm do not match the ones from the robot. But after applying other steps (when the robot is already being accelerated) the difference of the positions was still observable. (see picture). So it is basically does not matter which action I choose, it will never be reached within the provided  timestep `dt`. So I guess there is some king of kinematics behind the MuJoCo interface which reduces the action so that the robot can decelerate within next few timesteps to the point I provided earlier. (if I will not provide a new one).

Yes, there is a limit maximum change in position in `_set_action` function, which I removed.

**The question:** Is it possible to somehow disable this "deceleration" kinematics so that the point will be achieved without any delay and deceleration? On the picture below I want the "actual" position to be in "destination".

On the picture below I marked the start location with the big blue cross and the destination with the green cross. The blue line is the passed trajectory. The small blue cross denotes the actual achieved position, which is not the same as the green cross.

[image: My guess of how the velocity is computed]
[[image: MuJoCo FetchReach action not achieved]

This question relates to my previous issue o mujoco-py github: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/696

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are expecting to literally set the velocities or accelerations? That is not how actuation works. Actuators apply *forces*, the resulting motion depends on many other things (inertia, damping etc.).

The issue is really with your MPC algorithm. You cannot just invent a kinematic trajectory. You need to create trajectories via the same dynamics that the actual system has. In other words your MPC algorithm needs to output a sequence of actions (`ctrl` vectors) such that the resulting trajectory after rollout achieves whatever it is that you want it to achieve (presumably via a cost/reward).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In FetchReach-v1 I can only set the change of position (dx, dy, dz). It does not matter which change of position I set, it will always compute another one. It feels like there is some kind of an algorithm in between GYM environment and MuJoCo actuators which computes changes of rotation angles of the robot from my changes of positions. How can I control all actuators by myself directly?

Comment: Because, in the example I presented above, if I would choose a point a bit far away from the point I have chosen right now it will achieve this one in dt. So basically it is able to achieve my destination, but because of the deceleration it does not do it.